# Why portable Python is not working with relative path?

Tags: python, pyvenv

I want to make a portable python, so i use relative path in pyvenv.cfg like this:

```
home = ..\python310
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.9
```

But i keep getting this error (everything else is okay i think):

```
No Python at '"..\python310\python.exe'
```

It can be seen that there is a " symbol in the path, but i didn't put it there, it is likely causing the problem.

When im using absolute path everything is okay:

```
home = C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\PortablePython\python310
```

Comment: It's been an open issue known for at least 3 years. Found after 1 second of Google searching. Please don't use this site as a Google substitute. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83650

Comment: Sorry i didn't find it with Google. Anyway, what was the solution?

Comment: There is none unless you programmatically generate the cfg file. If you'd read that link you would see that `virtual environments are not designed to be portable in general, so this would be a fundamental change in the design and purpose of virtual environments.`